# How to make floating menu which stays in place until you scroll over it

Tags: jquery, menu, sidebar

I want to make a menu that is fixed. But I want it only to be fixed if i've scrolled past it.
Actually I want it just like the "how to .." menu on the question ask part of stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

I thought you need jquery to do such things, but i really don't know much about jquery.

I use this code for the menu and i want that to  float. So the whole sidebar div needs to float.:

```
 <div id="sidebar">
     <div>
        <h2 class="title">Sites</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a>first li</a></li>
                <li><a>second li</a></li>
                <li><a>third li</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="title">Sites</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a>first li</a></li>
                <li><a>second li</a></li>
                <li><a>third li</a></li>
            </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how I can let it float to the top of the page, but i want it to float in a wrapper.

I hope you guys can help me.

**EDIT**

now i have the floating menu with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 15;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

But there is a really annoying bounce effect when I scroll down. Is there a way to remove that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** You'll bind to the [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event of the window and check whether the current [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) (distance in pixel from the top of the page to the pixel currently at the top of your viewport) is larger than the distance from the top of the page to the top of your  sidebar.
If this is given you'll set the difference as marginTop to make the sidebar stay in the visible area.

See at http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ for an example and further information.

Comment: A small question, can i get rid of the bounce thing when you scroll down? Or is it that he just must load the page and because of that has a bounce in it. Because I want it to be more like when it would be fixed.

Comment: To avoid the animation replace both `$sidebar.stop().animate({` in the example code linked above with `$sidebar.css({` to not animate the change of the margin-top but set it immediately. Hope this this helps as I'm not sure what is meant with "bouncing".